# How do I amend my .htaccess rules to allow more than 1 parameter?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL with 3 parameters like the following

`http://example/songs.php?name=name&uploadedby=xyz&cat=rock`

before I had the URL with just 1 parameter like this:

`http://example/songs.php?name=name`

The rules in my *`.htaccess`* file are as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ /songs.php?name=$1
```

Currently it works for 1 parameter only.

How can I make this work for 1 or more parameters?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /songs.php?name=$1&uploadedby=$2&cat=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```